# Need guidance with Spinnaker API for deleting a Spinnaker pipeline

Tags: spinnaker

I am using Spinnaker to create a deployment of application on Kubernetes cluster. This is done using C# code, which already exists. Now, I want to create a delete manifest stage and use selector to delete multiple resources:
https://www.spinnaker.io/reference/pipeline/stages/#delete-manifest

So, need the following:

- Delete the application that was deployed using the Spinnaker pipeline
- Stop the pipeline.
- Delete the pipeline

Any references and snippets will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need to stop pipeline after delete stage?

Any way:

Find and Delete Resource

https://www.spinnaker.io/reference/pipeline/stages/#find-artifacts-from-resource
https://www.spinnaker.io/reference/pipeline/stages/#delete-manifest

Stop/Cancel pipeline

https://www.spinnaker.io/reference/api/docs.html#api-Pipelinecontroller-cancelPipelineUsingPUT1

Delete pipeline

https://www.spinnaker.io/reference/api/docs.html#api-Pipelinecontroller-deletePipelineUsingDELETE